# Is it posible to create a loop in ArrayAdapter method getView

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I have a silly question, here is my LevelsAdapter class for LinearLayout. I use it to display levels in my activity. In getView method I use "if(level.getLevel() == 1)" to get level ID, I want to ask if it is possible to create a loop in order to do that? It would be bad with my implementation if there was 100 levels or more to check.

```
private class LevelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Level> {

        private ArrayList<Level> levelsList;

        public LevelsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Level> levelsList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, levelsList);
            this.levelsList = new ArrayList<Level>();
            this.levelsList.addAll(levelsList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView level;
            TextView levelQuestionsCount;
            TextView lockedLevelContainer;
            Button start;
            RelativeLayout levelLayout;
            LinearLayout levelLayoutInner;
            LinearLayout unlockedLevelContainer;
            ImageView locklevel;
        }

        private void unlock(ViewHolder holder){
            holder.lockedLevelContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.locklevel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private void lock(ViewHolder holder, int toUnlock){
            holder.unlockedLevelContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.lockedLevelContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.lockedLevelContainer.setText("Level is locked. Answer "+ (toUnlock - countSolved) +" questions to unclock.");
            holder.locklevel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.level1, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.level = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.level);
                holder.levelQuestionsCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.levelQuestionsCount);
                holder.lockedLevelContainer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lockedLevelContainer);
                holder.start = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLevel);
                holder.levelLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.levelLayout);
                holder.levelLayoutInner = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.levelLayoutInner);
                holder.unlockedLevelContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unlockedLevelContainer);
                holder.locklevel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.locklevel);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        D.sh("Clicked");

                        Button start = (Button) v;
                        Level level = (Level) start.getTag();

                        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LevelActivity.class);
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        dialogIntent.putExtra("level", level.getLevel());
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Level level = levelsList.get(position);

            holder.levelLayoutInner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_level_repeat);

            if(level.getLevel() == 1) {
                holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level1_button);

                if(countSolved >= Level.L1_TO_UNLOCK){  
                    unlock(holder);
                } else {
                    lock(holder, Level.L1_TO_UNLOCK);
                }

            }

            if(level.getLevel() == 2) {
                holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level2_button);

                if(countSolved >= Level.L2_TO_UNLOCK){  
                    unlock(holder);
                } else {
                    lock(holder, Level.L2_TO_UNLOCK);
                }

            }

            if(level.getLevel() == 3) {
                holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level3_button);

                if(countSolved >= Level.L3_TO_UNLOCK){  
                    unlock(holder);
                } else {
                    lock(holder, Level.L3_TO_UNLOCK);
                }

            }

            if(level.getLevel() == 4) {
                holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level4_button);

                if(countSolved >= Level.L4_TO_UNLOCK){  
                    unlock(holder);
                } else {
                    lock(holder, Level.L4_TO_UNLOCK);
                }
            }

            if(level.getLevel() == 5) {
                holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level5_button);

                if(countSolved >= Level.L5_TO_UNLOCK){  
                    unlock(holder);
                } else {
                    lock(holder, Level.L5_TO_UNLOCK);
                }

            }


            holder.level.setText("Level "+level.getLevel());
            holder.levelQuestionsCount.setText(level.getSolved() + "/" + level.getTotal());

            holder.level.setTag(level);
            holder.start.setTag(level);
            return convertView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any loop in your getView.

Comment: you probably need tables and arrays, but I don't see where you would put a loop.

Comment: I have 5 if conditionals, I wonder if it is possible to change them with for loop.

Comment: i really don't see how you would do that.

Comment: you should put the background resource and the L*_TO_UNLOCK value in the Level object.

Answer (score 0):

njzk2, I used your idea.

```
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                if(level.getLevel() == i) {

                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("level" + i + "_button" , "drawable", getPackageName());
                    holder.levelLayout.setBackgroundResource(resID);

                    if(countSolved >= level.getToUnlock()){ 
                        unlock(holder);
                    } else {
                        lock(holder, level.getToUnlock());
                    }

                }   
            }
```